# Have Ritchey Logic cleats changed in 15 years?

Tags: pedals, pedals-clipless

I ride very old Ritchey Logic pedals (model year ~1998), with original cleats (look like the red ones below):

[image: Old Ritchey Logic]

Since those have long been out of stock, I'd like to buy newer ones, the Logic V4 Comp, looking like the black one:

[image: Ritchey Logic V4 Comp]

Question: does anybody know, whether Ritchey cleats for old Logic pedals are still compatible with the new ones? I'd be grateful for a non-speculative, definite answer.

Comment: Would the new ones not come with some new cleats?

Comment: It's not relevant. I have two bikes, but one pair of shoes.

Comment: So on the other bike the very old Ritchey Logic pedals are fine?

Comment: Yes, they are fine. I still don't feel it's in any way relevant, but since you asked, the full story is: around 2000 I bought 2 pairs of RL pedals for 2 bikes, but finally I was using only one of them, the other rested on a shelf. The former eventually failed last year, having gone through about 40.000 km. Now I have a fresh pair of thoroughly tested, quality pedals. Correction: had. My wife confiscated them last week in exchange for her Shimano M-520, which suck. I need good old Ritcheys again. Please don't ask now if I don't happen to have another pair of shoes, or something like that.

Comment: Both look a lot like Wellgo designs, so I'd guess they are compatible. A friend of mine had Wellgos similar to the red Ritcheys and they also worked great with SPD cleats :)